# Selectize.js: Click on optgroup and select all child options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, selectize.js

Is there option in **selectize.js** to choose all child options when a parent **optgroups** is selected.

Multi Select list is populated using the example described in
https://github.com/sjhewitt/selectize.js/blob/optgroups/examples/optgroups.html#L59

```
$('#select-animal').selectize({
    options: [
        {class: 'mammal', value: "dog", name: "Dog" },
        {class: 'mammal', value: "cat", name: "Cat" },
        {class: 'mammal', value: "horse", name: "Horse" },
        {class: 'mammal', value: "kangaroo", name: "Kangaroo" },
        {class: 'bird', value: 'duck', name: 'Duck'},
        {class: 'bird', value: 'chicken', name: 'Chicken'},
        {class: 'bird', value: 'ostrich', name: 'Ostrich'},
        {class: 'bird', value: 'seagull', name: 'Seagull'},
        {class: 'reptile', value: 'snake', name: 'Snake'},
        {class: 'reptile', value: 'lizard', name: 'Lizard'},
        {class: 'reptile', value: 'alligator', name: 'Alligator'},
        {class: 'reptile', value: 'turtle', name: 'Turtle'}
    ],
    optgroups: [
        {value: 'mammal', label: 'Mammal'},
        {value: 'bird', label: 'Bird'},
        {value: 'reptile', label: 'Reptile'}
    ],
    optgroupField: 'class',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: ['name']
});
```

considering above data, requirement is: when **mammal** class/parent option is clicked, it should select all child options like **Dog, Cat, Horse and Kangaroo**